# A few question about Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a few question using Sencha Touch as application for iPad.

1. It will be working only when you are connect to internet?
2. it is easy to understand?
3. It is norm to use for simple applications?
4. If i dont have a internet connection for my iPad it wont be working?

thank you!

Comment: 2/3. I've found that Sencha Touch is quite difficult to learn. For something much more simpler, check out Dashcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It can run fully disconnected, though most apps would be designed to operate in concert with some kind of web service for their data. For disconnected operation, you'd want to be sure that all the necessary files are available by setting the [cache manifest](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) accordingly
2. That's highly subjective.
3. Simple apps would normally just use HTML/JavaScript/CSS, usually with help from something like jQuery. There's no reason you can't use Sencha Touch for such apps, though, especially if you already use it for other reasons.
4. That's just a repeat of the first question!

Answer (score 0):

1/ Your client has to be connected somehow to the web server, either via internet, LAN or local.

2/ It´s difficult to answer such a question. It may be really easy for you and pretty difficult for me.

3/ It´s not a norm for anything. It´s just a very good (personnal view) library to develop web applications.

4/ You don´t need internet. But you do need a web server. Well, you can even run the app locally without web server but for very small and limited apps. For regular apps, you need at least a web server, and it makes no sence to run it local to the client. For instance, you might develop an application to be run in a small LAN, and then internet is not a must. The application would be hosted in a web server within the LAN and clients then connect to the server via this LAN, wired or wireless.

I hope this helps.

Dalton

Answer (score 0):

1. Initially you need to be connected to the internet. But as @Marcelo says, if you have the cache manifest file set up, the browser won't try to download the site if you are offline but use it's cache of the site. The cavet of this is that if you are using serverside scripts to get data. This can be solved by using localstorage but it can be a little tricky setting that up.
2. Like most things, there is a learning curve. If you have ever used Ext JS 3 (or before) you will mostly feel right at home.
3. Sencha Touch is great for creating web applications. For smaller, simple sites, it may be a little large of a download. You can create a custom build of Sencha Touch using the JSB file and doing a build.
4. Same as #1